# How to read an .XLSX (Excel 2007) file using ADO.NET? I am finding "Could not find installable ISAM"-error

Tags: ado.net, c#-2.0, excel-2007, oledb, openxml

I need to work in `.net 2.0`. So I can't use OpenXML.

This is my source code and I have already Installed `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`.

But still getting the exception:

> "Could not find installable ISAM".

I have also tried `"Extended Properties=Excel 8.0"` in the connection string.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();

    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|Data Directory|\HSC.xlsx;Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;");           
    OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter= new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);

    dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to Carl Prothman, that should be

```
 Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;
```

-- http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007

In more detail:

```
 OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Docs\\Book2.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'");
```

Note the single quotes.

Comment: In case it helps someone else: I had to remove the semicolon after `HDR=YES;'` or I got the error "format of the initialization string does not conform to the OLE DB specification"

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the Microsoft OpenXML 2.0 SDK for this kind of functionality. It has a really nice interface, and it does not put a demand on having Office installed on the machine reading the XLSX file which is a good thing.

I'm writing this from my mobile, so hard to provide a link, but a Google search should easily find it for you.

Give it a try. I think you will like it.

**EDIT**

If you *have* to use .NET 2.0, you can go for using the JET variant of the `OleDb` instead.

That means you will do something like this to connect:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + 
                 "Data Source='" + filename + "';" + 
                 "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=No;IMEX=1;\"";);
```

Then you can query it like in your example above:

```
OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", connection);
```

Try it! Just note that `Jet` have some strange logic of deciding if a column is numeric or not. See the following SO questions for details: [Problem with using OleDbDataAdapter to fetch data from a Excel sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817378/problem-with-using-oledbdataadapter-to-fetch-data-from-a-excel-sheet)

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that the connection string looks like the following ( even if you are accessing microsoft excel version 10 ->

```
MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;
Data Source='D:\csharp-Excel.xls';Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=Yes;'");
```