# C# VS2010 Error: Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, excel, oledb

I am trying to use the OleDb connection to fill a data table with data from an excel file, however I am receiving the following error: "Could not find installable ISAM".

Any help would be much appreciated.

I have tried the advice from other similar error posts to no avail.

```
         string cnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;'C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ExcelTest1\ExcelTest1\CapitalPlan.xlsx';Extended Properties=" + "\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"";
         DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        `string sql = "Select * From [Sheet1$]";`

        `using (OleDbConnection cn = new OleDbConnection(cnStr))
        {
            using (OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, cn))
            {
                adapter.Fill(dt);
            }
        }`
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Answer below:

```
string cnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\\Docs\\Book2.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 xml;HDR=YES;'";
```

It was the syntax in the OleDb connection string.

More detail:
[How to read an .XLSX (Excel 2007) file using ADO.NET? I am finding "Could not find installable ISAM"-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005704/how-to-read-an-xlsx-excel-2007-file-using-ado-net-i-am-finding-could-not-fi?rq=1)