# How to Export values to excel with leading '0'

Tags: c#, .net

I'm developing a web application. I'm facing a problem when exporting the values in the grid to excel. I have declared a column with data type as string but the column holds the integer values. When i open the exported excel, the string column is displayed as integer and the leading '0' in that field gets deleted. how to handle this.

Eg. the filed contains the vl

Comment: How do you communicate with excel? Do you use Jet?

Comment: I think I had the same problem as you earlier. Please check this [question][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817378/problem-with-using-oledbdataadapter-to-fetch-data-from-a-excel-sheet

Answer (score 0):

export the values with surrounding ' or " symbols, then it's taken as a string

Like:

```
col1;col2;col3
'001';'002';'003'
```