# Excel-to-SQL Server Data Connections Parameters Sending Wrong Data Type

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

a bit stumped on this one.  Someone I work with is having some troubles with Parameters in an Excel Data Connection query to SQL Server.  When he changes a SQL query from hard-coded date filters to using parameters and cell values, he gets an error (cannot convert character string to smalldatetime).  It is worth noting that the query has multiple subqueries.  I did a bit of research and found the following:

1) In the NetMon capture of the original query with one hard-coded date changed to a parameter reference, Excel is sending the parameter datatype as varchar(50).
2) When I change the query to have all dates changed to parameter references, only the final parameter is being sent as varchar(50), the rest are being sent as smalldatetime (which matches the table's data type).
3) When I change the query to remove the subqueries *but nothing else*, the query returns properly and Excel sends the correct data type.  In this situation there is just one parameter.
4) When I dump the query into a stored procedure and call that from the same Excel data connection, the parameters all work correctly.

I tried moving the cells around so that I could see if it was a [JET-like problem of Excel checking the top 8 rows of data to determine datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3817416/493055) - not the problem.

Why would this be happening?  As I mentioned - stumped.

The code is essentially like this:

```
SELECT Name
, Sum(Sales) AS Sales
, (SELECT SUM(Cost) FROM Costcenter where Date > ? AND Date <= ?) As Costs
FROM SalesTable
Where Date = ?
Group by name
Order by name
```

And the final `?` (in the `WHERE` clause is the one giving me grief.

Comment: I can't answer your question "why would this by happening". But I'd surmise a solution might be to write a function which receives the cell references as arguments and builds an overall query string, and just use that resultant string as the query rather than passing the values of the references as parameters through the connection.

Comment: Yeah, this might end up being the best solution.  It's suboptimal because all end users may not have a good understanding of which datatype to use, but for this specific user it would work.  I figured this would be too involved for the gain I'd get out of it, but in the end it could work out.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The colleague who was having the issue has found the following workaround.  When entering a date into a cell, use the following formula:

`=TEXT(EDATE('3/13/2013'),0),"MM/DD/YYYY")`

Not ideal, but it's a quick fix for users who just need to get at the data.